# Output event not triggering action on component

Tags: angular, typescript

**Edit:** [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xy1Jg91ZxTFf21y9lSRd?p=preview)

**Edit 2:** The difference between the Plunker post and the actual code seems to be that the `clickOutside` event has no observers attached to it in the latter.

I need to implement a way to close a modal when the user clicks outside of a component in an Angular4 application. To achieve this, I created a simple `ClickOutside` directive hat should trigger the `closeModal` method on the component when such a click occurs. The event is emitted, but the method is not called however.

The **ClickOutside** directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        let clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit();
        }
    }
}
```

The **template**:

```
<div (clickOutside)="closeModal()">
// some more HTML
```

The **component** to which the above template belongs:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foobar',
    templateUrl: './foobar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foobar.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class FoobarComponent {

    // some more code

    closeModal() : void {
        this.showModal = false;
    }

}
```

What am I missing here? Did I forget something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `this.clickOutside.emit()` is called? Have you tried `this.clickOutside.emit(null);`?

Comment: Yes, it's being triggered. Put a breakpoint there and it gets hit. `this.clickOutside.emit(null);` also doesn't trigger the `closeModal()` method on the component.

Comment: I'd suggest you try to reproduce in a Plunker. There is nothing wrong in the code you posted.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added a link to a Plunker example. It works fine there though.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on on your site then.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When I debug, I see that the `clickOutside` event emitter has an empty observers array. That doesn't seem right to me. Or is it? This is the first time I'm actually using `@Output`.

Comment: Is it different than in the Plunker? I haven't investigated that close. I'm not using TS myself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The Plunker example does seem to have an observer subscribed to the `clickOutside` event as can be seen in the console output: `Number of observers: 1`. What could cause Angular to not subscribe the observer?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Never heard of such an issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm having pretty much same problem now, (only I try to emit event from directive) did you ever manage to find source of this?